# angularjs push function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to make a single page angular js application but while adding to the list "schedulelist" only the latest record are getting pushed into the list and all the previous records are getting replaced by the latest record

This is my Html:

```
 <table class="table1" cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 border=0>
  <div ng-repeat="scheduleDTO in schedules">
<tr>
<td>
       <SELECT id="days" name="days" class="form-right" style="width:90%" ng-model="scheduleDTO.day_of_the_week" required>

                    <OPTION selected value="Monday">Monday</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Tuesday">Tuesday</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Wednesday">Wednesday</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Thursday">Thursday</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Friday">Friday</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Saturday">Saturday</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="Sunday">Sunday</OPTION>              
        </SELECT>

</td>
<td>
       <SELECT id="start_time" name="Start" class="form-right" style="width:90%" ng-model="scheduleDTO.start_time" required>
                    <OPTION value="1:00">01:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="2:00">02:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="3:00">03:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="4:00">04:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="5:00">05:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="6:00">06:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="7:00">07:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="8:00">08:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION selected value="9:00">09:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="10:00">10:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="11:00">11:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="12:00">12:00</OPTION>
        </SELECT>

</td>
<td>
<SELECT id="start" name="am" class="form-right" style="width:90%" ng-model="scheduleDTO.start_time_meridiem"required>
                    <OPTION selected value="AM">AM</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="PM">PM</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<td><SELECT  id="end_time"class="form-right" name="end" style="width:90%" ng-model="scheduleDTO.end_time" required>
                    <OPTION value="1:00">01:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="2:00">02:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="3:00">03:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="4:00">04:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION selected value="5:00">05:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="6:00">06:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="7:00">07:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="8:00">08:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="9:00">09:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="10:00">10:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="11:00">11:00</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="12:00">12:00</OPTION>
        </SELECT>

        </td>
<td>

<SELECT id="end" name="pm" class="form-right" style="width:90%" ng-model="scheduleDTO.end_time_meridiem" required>
                    <OPTION value="AM">AM</OPTION>
                    <OPTION selected value="PM">PM</OPTION>
</SELECT>


</td>
<td><input type="button" class="addSch" ng-click="add(scheduleDTO)" value="Add Schedule" style="width:90%"> <!-- add_schedule(); -->

</td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
<table align='center' class="table1" cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="table" border=0>

<tr ng-repeat="ScheduleDTO in schedulelist">

<td>{{scheduleDTO.day_of_the_week}}</td>
<td>{{scheduleDTO.start_time}}</td>
<td>{{scheduleDTO.start_time_meridiem}}</td><td>To</td>
<td>{{scheduleDTO.end_time}}</td>
<td>{{scheduleDTO.end_time_meridiem}}</td>
<td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' ng-click="remove(scheduleDTO)"></td>


</table>
```

This is rthe controller:

```
$scope.schedulelist = [

    ];


    $scope.add = function (schedule) 
            {                   schedule.volunteer_id="";
                                schedule.sid="";
                   $scope.schedulelist.push({"ScheduleDTO":schedule});
                    alert(angular.toJson($scope.schedulelist));
            };
    $scope.remove = function(schedule) { 
                var index = $scope.schedulelist.indexOf(schedule);
                $scope.schedulelist.splice(index, 1);     
                    alert(angular.toJson($scope.schedulelist));
            };
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Angular#copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to avoid reference copy in the modal,

which is the same one getting used again and data is overwritten.

```
$scope.schedulelist.push({"ScheduleDTO":angular.copy(schedule)});
```

Answer (score 0):

there is only one instance of an object in javascript if you create an object there will be single reference to it, i.e if you change in the object all the values will be changed so even you are changing the value every time it all the values pushed in the array will refer to the same object.
better solution will be

```
 $scope.add = function (scheduleValue) 
        {
          var schedule=angular.copy(scheduleValue);
               schedule.volunteer_id="";
                            schedule.sid="";
               $scope.schedulelist.push({"ScheduleDTO":schedule});
                alert(angular.toJson($scope.schedulelist));
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

> $scope.schedulelist.push({"ScheduleDTO":schedule});

each team a record is pushed to the ScheduleDTO property of the object and each time new entry replaces the old one.

You can do something like this

```
$scope.add = function (schedule) 
{                   schedule.volunteer_id="";
schedule.sid="";
//Create an array of ScheduleDTO 
if(  $scope.schedulelist.ScheduleDTO instanceof Array == false) {
    $scope.schedulelist.ScheduleDTO = []
}
//Push the schedule into the array
$scope.schedulelist.ScheduleDTO.push(schedule);
alert(angular.toJson($scope.schedulelist));
};
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help. but there is one more issue. while printing it prints the latest record only

Comment: can you plz create a fiddle. it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular copy and and also change variable name from select box and list. [Please check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v327xf8b/12/)

```
 (function($){

try{
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
demoApp.controller('demoController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.schedulelist = [

    ];


    $scope.add = function (scheduleObject) {   

                            var schedule = angular.copy(scheduleObject)
                  schedule['volunteer_id']="";
                  schedule['sid']="";

                  $scope.schedulelist.push(
                    {"ScheduleDTO":schedule}
                  );
            };
    $scope.remove = function(schedule) { 
                var index = $scope.schedulelist.indexOf(schedule);
                $scope.schedulelist.splice(index, 1);     
                    alert(angular.toJson($scope.schedulelist));
            };

            }])
}catch(e){
console.log(e)
}

})(jQuery)
```